# How to hover area map - Responsive

Tags: dictionary, hover, area, rollover

I'm trying to do a hover event on a responsive area map, so I found this :

http://www.andensolutions.com/blog/responsiveImagePaths

But I can't manage to apply this on my project.

I'm a beginner in web and jQuery stuffs. Can someone tell me where Should I call my script ?

Thanks in advance

Here is the concerned code :

```
 <title>Montesson ville ou campagne ?</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="A compléter (déscription rapide du site sur Google)" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="Montesson Périurbain ZAC rural urbain île-de-france agriculture écologie" />
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><script src="css/ie/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.scrolly.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery-maphilight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/map_rollover.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jQuery-rwdImageMaps.js"></script>

    <noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skel.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-desktop.css" />
    </noscript>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script></head>


<body>


    <!-- Première partie (Carte) -->

    <!-- On met notre carte ici -->
    <div id="BoiteImage">
        <img src="images/carte_ZAC-2-5.jpg" title="La carte" usemap="#Map" class="image" />
        <map name="Map">
            <!-- On utilise une MAP pour faire corresponde chaque zone de la caret à un lien -->
            <area id="Map" shape="poly" coords="427,513,548,363,658,434,488,618,446,538,446,604,489,618" 
                  href="les_zones_cultivees.html" title="Les Logements" />
        </map>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the link is good, thanks. got it working, after I read the comments ;) the canvas ist behind the img. so for quick example reduce the opacity of the img using firebug or similar tool. and if console says, that coords are not in the format of x1,y1,etc., then simply copy/pase the coords from the area from the map from the link from above #from :D .. and implement all js files given in script.rar/downloadlink.